# Is there any way to set up VS Code to check that SQL queries are valid

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to set up a type checker to validate that SQL queries are using the right columns from the right tables and the right dialect?

Comment: And how would it know what the right columns and tables are?

Comment: It connects to the database

Comment: Connecting establishes you have the correct credentials, not whether you are doing correct queries. A program could determine whether tables and columns exist, but whether they are the right ones for a given query is up to the user.

Comment: I meant, if it is connected to the DB it can actually inspect the columns and tables and reference that against that query.

Comment: That would some sort of autocomplete. That would establish the tables and  columns exist, it still would not determine that the query is correct.

Comment: Autocompleting tables and columns is 90% of the way there though.

Comment: Also I'm imagining it's fairly trivial to determine whether an SQL query is a read or a write and if it's a write you can just execute the query on the DB that will check for sure if the query is valid and get you the types.

Comment: 1) This sort of question falls under the *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more* close reason so at some point it will be closed. 2) It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. 3) *...fairly trivial to determine whether an SQL query is a read or a write ...* is not that trivial when you consider things like `select some_data_changing_function()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand you fully and also not sure how your vsCode is setup. My first instinct is that you need to install an extension thats specifically does SQL linting that detects syntax errors and enforcing code style.

search for SQLFluff and install it as as extension.

Comment: No that's not what I need thanks for trying though. I want type checking not formatting

Comment: For that you need to install database IDE's. Look up the following: DBeaver
DataGrip
Navicat
SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
MySQL Workbench

They all have very good Docs. Hope that helps.

And also linting includes type-checking so installing the extension will solve that for you.

Comment: Thanks but that won't help with getting proper type checking in my VS Code